# how to solve 'Invalid direction in positionRelativeToViewPoint:forCoordinate:inDirection:' error in ios 8/objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios8, core-plot

I am creating graph using core plot .I am having error in log

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid direction in positionRelativeToViewPoint:forCoordinate:inDirection:'

I am using following code for drawing axis

```
-(void)configureAxesDancis {
    // 1 - Create styles
    CPTMutableTextStyle *axisTitleStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    axisTitleStyle.color = [CPTColor blackColor];
    axisTitleStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
    axisTitleStyle.fontSize = 12.0f;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *axisLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    axisLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0f;
    axisLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor blackColor];
    CPTMutableTextStyle *axisTextStyle = [[CPTMutableTextStyle alloc] init];
    axisTextStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    axisTextStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
    axisTextStyle.fontSize = 11.0f;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *tickLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    tickLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor blackColor];
    tickLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0f;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *gridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    tickLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor blackColor];
    tickLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;
    // 2 - Get axis set
    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *) self.hostView.hostedGraph.axisSet;
    // 3 - Configure x-axis
    CPTAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
    x.title = @"Age In Days";
    x.titleTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;
    x.titleOffset = -30.0f;
    x.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
    x.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
    x.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle;
    x.majorTickLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
    x.majorTickLength = 2.0f;
    x.tickDirection = CPTSignNegative;
   // x.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:15.0];  //  x.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:15.0];

    NSInteger majorIncrementx = 5;
    NSInteger minorIncrementx = 1;
    CGFloat xMax = 20.0f;  // should determine dynamically based on max price
    NSMutableSet *xLabels = [NSMutableSet set];
    NSMutableSet *xMajorLocations = [NSMutableSet set];
    NSMutableSet *xMinorLocations = [NSMutableSet set];

    // NSInteger m = 0;
    for (NSInteger j = minorIncrementx; j <= xMax; j += minorIncrementx) {
        NSUInteger mod = j % majorIncrementx;
        if (mod == 0) {
            CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", (long)j] textStyle:x.labelTextStyle];
            NSDecimal location = CPTDecimalFromInteger(j-10);
            // CGFloat location = m+5;
            label.tickLocation = location;
            label.offset = -x.majorTickLength+10 - x.labelOffset+10;
            if (label) {
                [xLabels addObject:label];
            }
            [xMajorLocations addObject:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:location]];
        } else {
            [xMinorLocations addObject:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:CPTDecimalFromInteger(j)]];
        }
    }
    x.axisLabels = xLabels;
    x.majorTickLocations = xMajorLocations;
    x.minorTickLocations = xMinorLocations;



    // 4 - Configure y-axis
    CPTAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
    y.title = @"Width";
    y.titleTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;
    y.titleOffset = 40.0f;
    y.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
    y.majorGridLineStyle = gridLineStyle;
    y.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
    y.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle;
    y.labelOffset = -10.0f;
    y.majorTickLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
    y.majorTickLength = 4.0f;
    y.minorTickLength = 2.0f;
    y.tickDirection = CPTSignNegative;
    NSInteger majorIncrement = 1000;
    NSInteger minorIncrement = 1000;
    CGFloat yMax = 10000.0f;  // should determine dynamically based on max price
    NSMutableSet *yLabels = [NSMutableSet set];
    NSMutableSet *yMajorLocations = [NSMutableSet set];
    NSMutableSet *yMinorLocations = [NSMutableSet set];
    for (NSInteger j = minorIncrement; j <= yMax; j += minorIncrement) {
        NSUInteger mod = j % majorIncrement;
        if (mod == 0) {
            CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", (long)j] textStyle:y.labelTextStyle];
            NSDecimal location = CPTDecimalFromInteger(j/3);
            label.tickLocation = location;
            label.offset = -y.majorTickLength - y.labelOffset;
            if (label) {
                [yLabels addObject:label];
            }
            [yMajorLocations addObject:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:location]];
        } else {
            [yMinorLocations addObject:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:CPTDecimalFromInteger(j)]];
        }
    }
    y.axisLabels = yLabels;
    y.majorTickLocations = yMajorLocations;
    y.minorTickLocations = yMinorLocations;

}
```

App crashes when this function is calling.I don't understand.but few days back code is working fine,I made some changes in target .but after that this error is coming.please help out why this error is coming. Thank you!!!

Adding stack trace:

```
 Uncaught exception: Invalid direction in positionRelativeToViewPoint:forCoordinate:inDirection:
 2015-03-30 17:52:19.939 MyApp[4398:101971] Stack trace: (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103de4f35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000103a7dbb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103de4e6d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
3   MyApp                         0x00000001003fa1be -[CPTAxisLabel positionRelativeToViewPoint:forCoordinate:inDirection:] + 1998
4   MyApp                         0x00000001003b9423 -[CPTAxis updateMajorTickLabels] + 675
5   MyApp                         0x00000001003bbc85 -[CPTAxis setAxisLabels:] + 1685
6   MyApp                         0x00000001003065e0 -[MyAppBarChartViewController configureAxes] + 2496
7   MyApp                         0x000000010030477c -[MyAppBarChartViewController initPlot] + 124
8   MyApp                         0x0000000100304285 -[MyAppBarChartViewController viewDidLoad] + 533
9   UIKit                               0x0000000102208a90 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 738
10  UIKit                               0x0000000102208c8e -[UIViewController view] + 27
11  UIKit                               0x000000010224be80 -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:transition:shouldSetSelected:] + 360
12  UIKit                               0x0000000102248069 -[UITabBarController _setSelectedViewController:] + 311
13  UIKit                               0x000000010224b4e9 -[UITabBarController _tabBarItemClicked:] + 245
14  UIKit                               0x00000001020e48be -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
15  UIKit                               0x00000001023b8b76 -[UITabBar _sendAction:withEvent:] + 451
16  UIKit                               0x00000001020e48be -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
17  UIKit                               0x00000001021eb410 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467
18  UIKit                               0x00000001023bcfd1 -[UITabBar(Static) _buttonUp:] + 103
19  UIKit                               0x00000001020e48be -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
20  UIKit                               0x00000001021eb410 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467
21  UIKit                               0x00000001021ea7df -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 522
22  UIKit                               0x000000010212a308 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 735
23  UIKit                               0x000000010212ac33 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 683
24  UIKit                               0x00000001020f79b1 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246
25  UIKit                               0x0000000102104a7d _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 17370
26  UIKit                               0x00000001020e0103 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1961
27  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103d1a551 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
28  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103d1041d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
29  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103d0fa54 __CFRunLoopRun + 868
30  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103d0f486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
31  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010748a9f0 GSEventRunModal + 161
32  UIKit                               0x00000001020e3420 UIApplicationMain + 1282
33  MyApp                         0x00000001001f7075 main + 149
34  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000104a90145 start + 1
```

Comment: Where does it crash? Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: Even I am facing this crash. I upgraded the build settings of my app to include 64 bit architecture, added core plot library v1.5.1 (libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a, size 8.7 MB) in a static way. I tested on iPad 3 and iPhone 5c, no issues. I am facing this crash on iPhone 6 simulator. I guess the crash is on 64 bit architecture devices. Please help Eric.

Comment: I debugged the error: 'direction' variable is set on line 1757 of CPTAxis.m. It contains a garbage value, hence the crash. Please help Eric.

Comment: hi i have tried with 1.5.1 dll but geeting same error. then i try with this [link](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot) and make static lib and add the reference in my project and its works. plz try.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same error while building a scatter plot using the core plot framework. The same NSInvalidArgumentException that you mention in the subject would get thrown when the graph was attempting to update the ticker labels, as demonstrated by the last four methods to be called in your stack trace (shown below chronologically by call time):

```
[MyAppBarChartViewController configureAxes]
[CPTAxis setAxisLabels:]
[CPTAxis updateMajorTickLabels]
[CPTAxisLabel positionRelativeToViewPoint:forCoordinate:inDirection:]
```

What ended up causing the issue was setting the x-axis tick direction to negative, as shown in the following line:

```
 x.tickDirection = CPTSignNegative;
```

Changing the `tickDirection` to either `CPTSignNone` or `CPTSignPositive` fixed the issue for me. Not sure why yet, I haven't dug into it much more. Hope this helps!